# how add the exception handling after accpeting input in JTextField in java

Tags: java

This is the GUI form that I have created. The value is obtained from the text field and it is stored in the new variable. For some value, it needs to be converted into the integer type. I have converted the value to the integer type, but I am trying to handle the exception when the user doesn't enter any value in the text field. for that, I have used if statement. And for the next exception is when the user enters the string value into the integer field. So I am not been able to handle this exception properly. please help me in doing so.

```
public void addSeniorDev(){
    String plat=txt1.getText();
    String name = txt2 .gettText();
    String hours = txt3.getText();
    String period = txt4.getText();
    String salary = txt5.getText();
    if( plat==("") || name==("") || hours==("")|| period==("")|| salary== 
     ("")){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DA,"The field are left empty:");

    }try{
        int hours1 = Integer.parseInt(hours);
        int salary1 = Integer.parseInt(salary);
        int period1 = Integer.parseInt(period); 

    }catch(ArithmeticException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DA,"only number are accepted");

        }   
    }
```

Comment: Note that `String` has an `isEmpty()` method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot compare Strings like that. Use equals method or isEmpty() to check if String is empty. Second thing is that if String is not parsable to Integer it throws NumberFormatException not an ArithmeticException according to documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

```
public void addSeniorDev(){
    String plat=txt1.getText();
    String name = txt2 .gettText();
    String hours = txt3.getText();
    String period = txt4.getText();
    String salary = txt5.getText();
    if(plat.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || hours.isEmpty() || period.isEmpty()|| salary.isEmpty()) { // changed String comparison
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DA,"The field are left empty:");

    }try{
        int hours1 = Integer.parseInt(hours);
        int salary1 = Integer.parseInt(salary);
        int period1 = Integer.parseInt(period); 

    }catch(NumberFormatExceptione){ // Changed exception type
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DA,"only number are accepted");

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is never advisable to do like this

```
plat==("")
```

do it like this

```
StringUtils.isEmpty(plat)
```

and instead of putting integer parsing under try catch you can avoid it with

```
StringUtils.isNumeric(hours)
```

and if this condition comes out to false you can take the required action.

> Note : StringUtils is available under import apache.commons.lang3

Comment: what if I put the try catch inside the if statement.

Comment: @HardikPoudel It is very much possible, But still it won't be be suggested approach. As throwing and catching exception is an expensive approach and for these scenarios it should not be used